# ANDROID WEAR Api Level 23-25: setText returns nullreference exception error in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, wear-os

Alright here's the console output

```
06/15 19:40:58: Launching wear
$ adb push C:\Users\Remmie's\Downloads\Android_Wear_App\wear\build\outputs\apk\wear-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/remmies.com.android_wear_app
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/remmies.com.android_wear_app"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/remmies.com.android_wear_app
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "remmies.com.android_wear_app/remmies.com.android_wear_app.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: remmies.com.android_wear_app.test | remmies.com.android_wear_app
Connecting to remmies.com.android_wear_app
W/ActivityThread: Application remmies.com.android_wear_app is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk

              [ 06-15 19:41:45.351  1293: 1308 D/         ]
              HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa740d8e0, tid 1308
I/art: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8698', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1304)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/remmies.com.android_wear_app-2/lib/x86
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                  --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: remmies.com.android_wear_app, PID: 2047
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{remmies.com.android_wear_app/remmies.com.android_wear_app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                      at remmies.com.android_wear_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:100)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8698', transport: 'socket'
```

Here's the rect_activity_main xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="remmies.com.android_wear_app.MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear_square"
    android:background="@color/blue">


    <Button
        android:text="pulse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pulse"
        android:layout_weight="2.30" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the java MainActivity code file:

```
package remmies.com.android_wear_app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.wearable.view.WatchViewStub;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import java.util.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView mTextView;
    private FileOutputStream fos;
    private FileInputStream fis;
    private String content_string="Test in Progress";
    private TextView t;





   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final WatchViewStub stub = (WatchViewStub) findViewById(R.id.watch_view_stub);
        stub.setOnLayoutInflatedListener(new WatchViewStub.OnLayoutInflatedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {

                mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                if (mTextView != null) {
                    Log.println(Log.INFO, "NULLINFO", "mTextView is not null");
                }
                stub.findViewById(R.id.pulse).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Vibrator vibe= (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                        long[] vibrationPattern_2 = {0, 2000, 2000, 2000};
                        ///-1 - don't repeat
                        final int index_InPatternToRepeat = -1;
                        vibe.vibrate(vibrationPattern_2, index_InPatternToRepeat);


                    }
                });
            }
        });

                Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                long[] vibrationPattern = {0, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150};
                //-1 - don't repeat
                final int indexInPatternToRepeat = -1;
                vibrator.vibrate(vibrationPattern, indexInPatternToRepeat);

       String FILENAME = "hello_file.txt";
       String string = "hello world!";


       try {
           fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           fos.write(string.getBytes());
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       try {
           fos.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }


        //Try to read the file back?


       try {
           int content;

           fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
           while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
               // convert to char and display it
               content_string += (char) content;

            mTextView.setText("Test_Text");


           }





       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       try {
           fis.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }


    }

    //@Override
    //protected void onResume() {
       // super.onResume();
       // Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
       // long[] vibrationPattern = {0, 500, 50, 300};
        ///-1 - don't repeat
        //final int indexInPatternToRepeat = -1;
        //vibrator.vibrate(vibrationPattern, indexInPatternToRepeat);
    //}
```

The snippet that needs attention is:

```
//Try to read the file back?


       try {
           int content;

           fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
           while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
               // convert to char and display it
               content_string += (char) content;

            mTextView.setText("Test_Text");


           }
```

I have also tried it with setting the mainview first like so:

```
mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
mTextView.setText("Test_Text");
```

Lastly here is the AndroidManifest.xml for android wear project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="remmies.com.android_wear_app">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />


    <application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
        android:value="true" />
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Other details:

Things to know are:
1-I have already tried restarting the Android Studio.
2-I have already tried clean and build again.
3-I have already tried googling for answers to similiar questions, and even solutions that were offered on other forums or sites say to do this exactly this way.
4-I have also tried instantiating a new TextView instance then using getviewbyId.
5- I have already tried changing it to use the this keyword like so:

```
this.mTextView.setText("Test_Text");
```

6- I've looked at this example specifically:
[AndroidWearButtonExample --Uses SetText](https://github.com/pethoalpar/AndroidWearButtonExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/pethoalpar/androidwearbuttonexample/MainActivity.java)

As far as I know I'm not doing anything wrong but I am no expert, all I want to do is change the text inside of a textview. Remember, I'm working with minSDK API 23. Newer things INCLUDING "getActivity()" do not even seem to show up in my intellisense or autocomplete or whatever it's called. Like some function names or keywords do. Infact it ends up red underlined like this:
[image: Cannot Resolve getActivity()]

I have seen some examples where getActivity is used to get the current application activity before trying to reference a layout object such as a textview. this won't work in my case!

Alright so with all that set and done please please can someone help me worse comes to worse I will even zip the entire project and send it over or upload all of it to github for inspection.

Comment: extends your class to AppCompatActivity

Comment: your class are not extending to Fragment, so `getActivity()` cannot be resolved.

Comment: @John it says cannot resolve symbol: AppCompatActivity and it is also higlighted in red. It also doesn't appear in autocomplete as an option.

Comment: Appcompatactivity requires you to compile support-v7

Comment: What variables are at line 100? One of them is null. If it's a view, you likely used findViewById  wrong

Comment: Yeah, not sure why he deleted

Comment: line 100: mTextView.setText("Test Text"); I did what John advised and removed the stub for the instantiation of mTextView it just says: mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2); It just doesn't work.. I don't know what I've done wrong to cause mTextView to be null. It should be a member of the activity class and inside the function onCreate should not be null because it's defined: Even when setting it like this: [ @Override public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) { mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);]

Comment: Can someone find me an example of setText which is fully compilable in debug through android studio AND targets MinSDK API level 21? Build target 25?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that mTextView is not a valid object outside the scope of:

```
 public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {
```

I was trying to reference mTextView within the scope of:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
```

Here, I did access mTextView fine but it is nullable which means it would not throw an error at all:

```
@Override
            public void onLayoutInflated(WatchViewStub stub) {

                mTextView = (TextView) stub.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                if (mTextView != null) {
                    Log.println(Log.INFO, "NULLINFO", "mTextView is not null");
                }
```

The correct answer to change the text of mTextView is to only do it within the scope of onLayoutInflated, which looking at my original post now I was not doing. I had actually tried to do it the other night within the scope of onLayoutInflated and it still gave the null error. Perhaps Android Studio is also buggy.. anyhow it is allowing me to change the Text in TextView now, the solution to remove stub was not correct.. I do not believe.

Lastly..
I had wrongly assumed that after mTextView had been instantiated within the scope of onLayoutInflated that it would be referencable as a non-null object at the end of the function's life cycle. That is incorrect... for whatever ungodly reason I don't know but the object simply becomes null again or loses it's reference... outside the scope of that function. 
The object symbol is a member of the class scope. 
It would still be helpful if someone can explain in the most technical and exact manner possible to me why java or the android API loses the reference to the object mTextView and all it's data at the end of the function onLayoutInflated.

Further thoughts: Is there a way to get a reference to the textView that ascends and remains within class scope and stays 'alive' and does not become null again for the whole rest of the application's life cycle?

Comment: I found out that if I pass an instance of mTextView within an onTick() of a countdown timer defined within the scope of when mTextView is initialized that the mTextView reference survives within onTick, and if I call any function from within onTick() of a timer, and pass the reference of mTextView to that function, the mTextView reference survives there as well. Fascinating..